# Quiz: How to integrate an alternative/a similar answer as declared correct in a UITextField

Tags: ios, swift

Dear StackOverflowers,

I did a search but couldn't find anything in here or Google. As a total beginner I hope not to beeing punished with these minus ratings :)

Imagine a little quiz. At App Start there's a randomly generated String from a Dictionary telling the correct answer. Let's say it's this Dictionary:

```
let dictionary: Dictionary = [0: "One", 1: "Two", 2: "Three", 3: "Four", 4: "Five"]
```

And now I'm generating a random String from it:

```
var randomNumber: Int = 0
var randomString: String = ""

randomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(dictionary.count)))
randomString = Array(dictionary.values)[randomNumber]
```

Now there's a Question and the code knows that the correct answer is randomString.
I have a TextField for the user to guess the answer. Type your answer, click on „guess“ and then there's a result displayed in a label, generated with...

```
if textField.text == randomString {
resultLabel.text = "Correct!"
} else {
resultLabel.text = "Wrong!" }
```

**Question:** Is it possible to make partially correct answers also being displayed as „Correct!“? Let's say the user types „4“ instead of „Four“. Or in another case the correct answer would be „Harry and the Turtle Tubes“ and the user just types „Harry and the Turtles“ (shorter) or „harry and the turtle tubes“ (all words written in lower case).

I'm thankful for all your hints and code snippets.

Have a great day
Patrick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to search for is "fuzzy string matching". You can [read about it on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximate_string_matching).

There are a number of Swift libraries that exist that implement this. You will need to find one that best suits your needs.

Good luck!

Comment: Oh, this is great @greymouser, thank you! That will be my first library implementation then. Much left to learn for me :)

Comment: thanks again. FuzzyMatchingSwift (see Github) did the job quite well. Although it‘s a bit slow in reaction (calculating the „fuzzyness“ it works fine. Thanks again for the hint. Marked as correct answer because there just is not _the_ one solution - as you wrote it.